# How to change a JSON value with python

Tags: python, json, database

hi there i m trying to make a trade bot its about rate of other minutes volume. but sometime when i get my api some times i get soo little numbers 
like 82.7641093 . i want to change "volume_traded" value. when its below 1500 i want my json as it is counted as 1500

```
  url_XRP5MIN = 
'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/ohlcv/POLONIEX_SPOT_XRP_BTC/latest? 
period_id=5MIN'
headers = {'X-CoinAPI-Key': 'YOUR APİ KEY'}
responseXRP5 = requests.get(url_XRP5MIN, headers=headers)

XRPLAST5Volume=responseXRP5.json()[0]['volume_traded']
print(XRPLAST5Volume)

"time_period_start": "2019-02-18T18:15:00.0000000Z",
"volume_traded": 171673.27542305,



"time_period_start": "2019-02-18T18:30:00.0000000Z",
"volume_traded": 82.76410936,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json, requests

url = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/ohlcv/POLONIEX_SPOT_XRP_BTC/latest?'

headers = {'X-CoinAPI-Key': 'YOUR APİ KEY'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

result = response.json()

print(result[0]['volume_traded'])
if float(result[0]['volume_traded']) <= float(1500):
    # do whatever like reset the value
    result[0]['volume_traded'] = 2500

print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
# notice the new value we set
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access JSON values as follows

```
print your_dict['key']
```

So to change a value, you can do something like

```
if float(your_dict['volume_traded']) < 1500:
    your_dict['volume_traded'] = 1500
```